# how to centre header on screen with multiple columns, with equal space on both sides using css angular 2+

Tags: html, css, angular

I have been trying to centre the small_wrapper1 div on my screen so that I have white space on both sides and the navbar displays right in the centre.
How do I create the navbar in such way that it shows an equal amount of whitespace on the different display settings. Or for instance show 100px of marign either side on 641px resolution and show 50px margin either side on 320px resolution, whilst showing the navbar in a nice format filling up the centre.

I have been playing with percentages and changing the width, but I struggle to find a responsive way so that it works on most screen formats.
Has to work on most platforms.

```css
 .small_wrapper1{
    z-index: 1000;
    font-size: 16px;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 85px;
    width: 90%;
    color:rgb(215,193,179);
    box-shadow: 0 7px 12px rgb(3, 3, 3);
    background-color: rgb(225, 233, 255);
    margin-left: 100px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 25px 25px (repeat, 100px) 50px;  
    grid-auto-rows: 30px;
    grid-gap: 5px;
    grid-template-areas:
    "h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 h6 h7 h8"
  }
```

```html
   <div class="wrapper">
       <div class="small_wrapper1">
        <div class="header1">Rank</div>
        <div class="header2">Grade</div>
        <div class="header3">Name</div>
        <div class="header4">Price</div>
        <div class="header5">Market Cap</div>
        <div class="header6">change(24hr)</div>
        <div class="header61">(24hr)</div>
        <div class="header7">change(7d)</div>
        <div class="header71">(7d)</div>
        <div class="header8"></div>
       </div>
       <ol style="color:rgb(0, 27, 87)">
        <div class="arrayOfGrade" *ngFor="let key of arrayOfGradedCoins; let i = index">
        <div class="small_wrapper">
        <div class="column1">test</div>
        <div class="column2">test2 </div>
        <div class="column3">test3</div>
        <div class="column4">test4</div>
        <div class="column5">test5</div>
        <div class="column6"</div>
        <div class="column7"</div>
       </div>
      </div>
    </ol>
   </div>
```

Comment: Start by writing valid HTML. A `<tr>` can be neither parent, nor child of a `<div>`

Comment: and fix you snippet, you need to separate html and css

Answer (score -1):

use `margin: 0 auto;` it will take in the devices width and automatically center.

Answer (score -1):

Your code wasn't totally clear, please read through the snippet.
I hope that helps you.

```css
.small_wrapper1{
  z-index: 1000;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 85px; /*this wil not work unless you use position: absolute;*/
  /*width: 90%;*/
  color:rgb(215,193,179);
  box-shadow: 0 7px 12px rgb(3, 3, 3);
  background-color: rgb(225, 233, 255);
  margin:0 100px; /* this margin is used when no media querys are active */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25px 25px (repeat, 100px) 50px;  
  grid-auto-rows: 30px;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-template-areas:
  "h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 h6 h7 h8"

  margin:0 auto; /*this wil exactly center the div inside its parent*/

}

/*Use media querys to apply changes to the css if the screen becomes a certain size*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .small_wrapper1 {
    margin: 0 50px; /*this margin in set when the screen has a maximum size of 600px*/
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <tr>
     <div class="small_wrapper1">
      <th class="header1">Rank</th>
      <th class="header2">Grade</th>
      <th class="header3">Name</th>
      <th class="header4">Price</th>
      <th class="header5">Market Cap</th>
      <th class="header6">change(24hr)</th>
      <th class="header7">change(7d)</th>
      <th class="header8"><input class="textSearch" type="text" style="background-color: rgb(215,193,179); border: none; padding: 0; color: black " placeholder="search" [(ngModel)]="filterString" (keyup)="applyfilter()"> 
      </th>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you Yorick I will give it a try, what is going on with all this negative voting? I will correct the snippet to be separated from HTML

Comment: I have updated the code it now also cointains the ordered list code as I am running into issues. If I don't use position absolute/ or position fixed: the ol code is moved sideways next to the small_wrapper instead of underneath. I am using margin: 0 auto; however the navbar keeps displaying to the left. Unless I add margin: 0 100px; Then it displays 100 from the left, however the best thing would be that it centres exactly on the screen. Within the wrapper div